# Discrete Wavelet Transform (Daubechies wavelet) of an array complex numbers

Tags: image-processing, complex-numbers, wavelet-transform

Say, I have a signal represented as an array of real numbers `y = [1,2,0,4,5,6,7,90,5,6]`. I can use Daubechies-4 coefficients `D4 = [0.482962, 0.836516, 0.224143, -0.129409]`, and apply a wavelet transform to receive high- and low-frequencies of the signal. So, the high frequency component will be calculated like this:

```
high[v] = y[2*v]*D4[0] + y[2*v+1]*D4[1] + y[2*v+2]*D4[2] + y[2*v+3]*D4[3],
```

and the low frequency component can be calculated using other D4 coefs permutation.

---

The question is: what if `y` is complex array? Do I just multiply and add complex numbers to receive subbands, or is it correct to get amplitude and phase, treat each of them like a real number, do the wavelet transform for them, and then restore complex number array for each subband using formulas `real_part = abs * cos(phase)` and `imaginary_part = abs * sin(phase)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle the case of complex data, you're looking at the [Complex Wavelet Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_wavelet_transform).  It's actually a simple extension to the DWT.  The most common way to handle complex data is to treat the real and imaginary components as two separate signals and perform a DWT on each component separately.  You will then receive the decomposition of the real and imaginary components.

This is commonly known as the **Dual-Tree** Complex Wavelet Transform.  This can best be described by the figure below that I pulled from Wikipedia:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Wavelets_-_DTCWT.png)</sup>

It's called "dual-tree" because you have two DWT decompositions happening in parallel - one for the real component and one for the imaginary.  In the above diagram, `g0/h0` represent the low-pass and high-pass components of the real part of the signal `x` and `g1/h1` represent the low-pass and high-pass components of the imaginary part of the signal `x`.

Once you decompose the real and imaginary parts into their respective DWT decompositions, you can combine them to get the magnitude and/or phase and proceed to the next step or whatever you desire to do with them.

---

The mathematical proof regarding the correctness of this is outside the scope of what we're talking about, but if you would like to see how this got derived, I refer you to the canonical paper by Kingsbury in 1999 in the work [*Image Processing with Complex Wavelets*](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsta.1999.0447).  Pay close attention to the noise filtering of images using the CWT - this is probably what you're looking for.